# Disabling touchpad acceleration

Tags: touchpad, asus, elantech, budgie

I'd like to disable the dreadful touchpad acceleration Ubuntu Budgie has enabled by default.

How could I do that (using the terminal)?

It's an Elantech touchpad so I can't use the [SynapticsTouchpad documentation in Ubuntu's Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad).

Thanks.